# Nodemailer connect to local docker-mailserver

Tags: mail-server, docker, node.js, docker-compose

I need to set up a local mail server and send emails from it. I use [docker-mailserver](https://hub.docker.com/r/tvial/docker-mailserver/) and try to connect to it from simple NodeJS script that uses [Nodemailer](https://nodemailer.com/).
For `docker-mailserver` setup I followed the guide from its docs and changed only the `DOMAINNAME` env var to domain name of my server. The resulting `docker port` for container is:

```
993/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:993
143/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:143
25/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:25
587/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:587
```

From the same machine that runs mailserver docker container I tried to run the mail-sending script, here is it's code:

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: '0.0.0.0',
    port: 587,
    secure: false, // true for 465, false for other ports
    auth: {
        user: 'user@domain.com',
        pass: 'password'
    },
    tls: { rejectUnauthorized: false },
    debug: true,
});

let mailOptions = {
    from: '"" <user@domain.com>',
    to: 'some_account@gmail.com',
    subject: 'Hello ✔',
    text: 'Hello world?',
    html: '<b>Hello world?</b>'
};

transporter.verify((error) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.error(error);
    }

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.error(error);
        }
        console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    });
});
```

But I get only `Error: Connection closed` error.

What is the thing I'm missing here to setup correct connection between script and container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default container are isolated in docker.
You can allow connection between containers in docker by adding link argument when creating your Container
USAGE :

```
Docker run -d --name node_mailer --link EMAIL_SERVER_CONTAINER_NAME nodemailer_image
```

Comment: And in the compose.yml? Just add Link?